# How can I make a grid of objects in a UIView subclass?

Tags: objective-c, grid

As of right now, I have a for loop in my view.m file, inside the drawRect method. I have the for loop displaying images across the x axis. What I would like to do is be able to make a grid of images not only on the x axis but also on the y axis. So in other words, your typical grid. I also would like to make each one of the repeating images in the grid an object with a few properties attached to it such as a bool, an id that I can retrieve it by when touched, and it's coordinates. How would I go about doing this in objective-c? Here is what I have so far, which is not much:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    int intX = 0; 
    int intCounter = 0;
    int intY = 0;
    for (intCounter = 0; intCounter < 10; intCounter++) {
        UIImage* pngLeaf = [UIImage imageNamed:@"leaf2.png"];
        CGRect imgRectDefault = CGRectMake(intX, 0, 34, 34);
        [pngLeaf drawInRect:imgRectDefault];
        intX += 32;
        intY += 32;
    }
}
```

Comment: SInce you're just starting this out, might I suggest you use UIImageViews inside a UIScrollView instead of subclassing UIView.  It will make your life much easier in the long run, and you can put whatever properties you want in your UIImageView subclass.

Comment: @Jay I just read the UIScrollView class reference and that defiantly sounds like a good idea. I'm still stuck on the hole grid thing though. I guess what i need is an array of object, including the UIImage views. I'm just not sure how to work with multidimensional arrays to make grids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have an easier time of it with UIViews.

Here's a grid routine - it could be written much more compactly but it is easier to understand with lots of vars explicitly declared. Put it in your main ViewController and call it in ViewWillAppear.

```
- (void)makeGrid
{


int xStart = 0;
int yStart = 0;
int xCurrent = xStart;
int yCurrent = yStart;

UIImage * myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"juicy-tomato_small.png"];

int xStepSize = myImage.size.width;
int yStepSize = myImage.size.height;

int xCnt = 8;
int yCnt = 8;

int cellCounter = 0;

UIView * gridContainerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:gridContainerView];

for (int y = 0; y < yCnt; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < xCnt; x++) {
         printf("xCurrent %d  yCurrent %d \n", xCurrent, yCurrent);

        UIImageView * myView = [[UIImageView  alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
        CGRect rect = myView.frame;
        rect.origin.x = xCurrent;
        rect.origin.y = yCurrent;
        myView.frame = rect;
        myView.tag = cellCounter;
        [gridContainerView addSubview:myView];

        // just label stuff
        UILabel * myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        myLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        myLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        myLabel.frame = rect;
        myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",cellCounter];
        [gridContainerView addSubview:myLabel];
        //--------------------------------

        xCurrent += xStepSize;
        cellCounter++;
    }

    xCurrent = xStart;
    yCurrent += yStepSize;
}

CGRect repositionRect = gridContainerView.frame;
repositionRect.origin.y = 100;
gridContainerView.frame = repositionRect;

}
```

Comment: @Jay everything works great. The only thing I had to change was where you have xCurrent = xCurrent. I just changed it to xCurrent = xStart.